# how to retrieve data from autocomplete textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am working on a stock management system and i added textbox with autocomplete codes..i have two forms one is items form and other is stock in. now i can able to get itemcodeID from stockin itemnumber textbox with autocomplete codes but when i select that item number its not giving me the description..i mean to say that if user search itemcode in stock in form then he should get description and quantity of that item automatically... i am using vb.net and ms sql .

my code for autocomplete

```
Private Sub getData(ByVal dataCollection As AutoCompleteStringCollection)
    Dim connetionString As String = Nothing
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    connetionString = ("Server= DESKTOP-QN6F623; Database = dbo_main;Integrated Security = false;User ID=dis;Password=0m3rP@ss")
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT itemnumber FROM items"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            dataCollection.Add(row(0).ToString())
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub stockin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Stockin_itemnumberTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    Stockin_itemnumberTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    Dim DataCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    getData(DataCollection)
    Stockin_itemnumberTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
End Sub
```

i need....when user write in itemnumber textbox he should get related details automatically related to that number...itemnumber of textbox is autocomplete .

Comment: "Automatically" from the user's perspective means that you write code to make it happen.  Where have you written any code to retrieve description or quantity values from the database or display them based on the user's selection?  You haven't written any such code, so of course it doesn't happen.  You need to make an attempt before posting a question here.  This is not a place that we explain how to do things.  It's a place where we help you fix issues with code you have written. If you haven't written any code, you have no issue to fix.

Comment: my friend i posted code as my attempt. i saw many questions where peoples got answers with explanations thats why i post my question here. no one is perfect and everyone need help to achieve goals . i only need help in my above mentioned code or if anyone give me a code or idea to do as per my requirement. try to help instead of getting rude bro.happy new year

Comment: The code you posted has got nothing to do with your stated aim. It retrieves specific data and uses that data in an autocomplete list on a `Textbox`.  The code you have is, as far as I can tell, working as it should. You said you wanted to do something else apart from that and you have shown no code that has anything to do with that other thing.  If you've made no attempt to do the thing that you want help doing then it's to early to post a question on that.  It's not rude to inform you that you are doing the wrong thing.  If you don't want to be criticised, don't do the wrong thing.